# Unable to trigger click on nav menu using cypress automation tool

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a navigation bar on my website and when I mouseover the nav bar, It shows list of menus. Now I am facing a problem, I am unable to click on Its 4th option. I give you example below.
If we run below code, It will show down the list of menus available in its Admistrtion menu.

```
    cy.get('#Administrationlink > :nth-child(1)').trigger('mouseover')
```

but when I run this code, It will not click on Its 4th positioned option

```
   cy.get('#Administrationlink div > ul > li:eq(6)').click()
```

or

```
   cy.get('#Administrationlink div > ul > li').eq(6).click()
```

I am also trying `.contains` etc but not working. Below error occurs all the time.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

```
Home | Adminstration | About Us
--------------------------------
     | Option 1      |
     | Option 2      |
     | Option 3      |
     | Option 4      |
```

This is navigation bar.
Its struture is 
ul => li -> a  under this li again ul=>li->a
First Big `UL` have 3 options in `LI` Home,Administration,About Us
Then Administration has `LI` and Then again UL and LI for option 1,2,3,4.

Does It make sense?

Comment: Do you have a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Try using a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: i write two lines code, and shared two lines with you.  getting this error.

Comment: I was wondering if you had the entire navigation bar posted anywhere or could post it somewhere for us to look at and help you debug. There must be more than just these two lines.

Comment: I looked up the `:eq()` selector and it looks to me like it is [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/). Could this maybe be the problem?

Comment: Dear @matthew-e-brown I edited the question. please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you are testing (the hover behaviour vs. the navigation itself), it might help to force click on the (invisible) item like `cy.click({force: true})`, see https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/click.html#Force-a-click-regardless-of-its-actionable-state.

To be able to locate the navigation item in a reliable (as opposed to the list ordering) manner, I typically add a unique data attribute and select by that, e.g. `cy.get('a[data-testid="nav-option-1"]').click({force: true})`

Here's a good read on this approach: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change